# which android versions allow the user to set granular developer options?

Tags: android, android-activity

I've can see that 4.2.x allows the user to modify developer options.  Among other things, he can check the "Don't keep activities" option.

What is the first Android version to give users this capability?

A google search was unproductive.  Seemingly all the hits relate to unlocking developer options in Android 4.2.x and don't mention prior versions.

Comment: When you created emulators for the different Android versions, and you looked in Settings in each, what did you learn?

Comment: I actually don't use the emulator.  I have a number of physical devices at my disposal and just build to those.  Unfortunately I updated a few of them and no longer have a 4.0.x device.  All the ones that were 4.0+ are now at 4.1 or 4.2.

Comment: Guess its time to figure out the emulator.